# Can TokensRegex rule annotate on the document level?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Here is the the problem. Let's say, I have this rule:

```
{
    pattern: ( [ner:/DATE|TIME/] ),
    action: ( Annotate($0, myNER, "MY_DATETIME" ) )
}
```

Instead of annotating the capture group $0, how can I specify the entire document, sort of like this:

```
{
    pattern: ( [ner:/DATE|TIME/] ),
    action: ( Annotate( <document>, myNER, "MY_DATETIME" ) )
}
```

This can be a very useful feature that allows annotating the whole document (or perhaps a sentence) when a specific token pattern is found. Thanks.

Comment: I think it might be possible.  The Annotate function takes in a CoreMap, and the overall document is a CoreMap.  I'm not quite sure how to get access to a specific CoreMap, so I'm going to ask the TokensRegex creator if she can help me.  Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

At the moment there isn't an implemented way to do this.  There isn't a direct way to get access to the CoreMap representing the document through TokensRegex.

What would be necessary is for every token to have a pointer to the document CoreMap, then you could access the overall document in the TokensRegex rules by looking at a specific token, but this would require making some changes to the code.

If you want to open a GitHub issue we could try to add this functionality in future versions.